# Like going from a Controller to Three20?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to implement such stinging Three20 of a button and change the xib of Three20?

```
if (!self.albumController) {
    self.albumController = [[AlThumbsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 //I put in initWithNibName?
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.albumController animated:YES];
[self.albumController release];
self.albumController = nil;
```

No way that is generated in three xib I have an example but I do not understand much.
Thanks for all

---

How to move from one view to another without having seen the other one ".xib"?

Comment: automatic translation incomprehensible

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to just construct a new controller.

`self.albumController = [[AlThumbsViewController alloc] init];`

You will need to make sure AlThumbsViewController supports this type of construction.